# Query group sum with cross apply

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Running this query:

```
select rpid, SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT, MIN(p.oid) as HomeID from LEDGER
cross apply 
(select top 1 p.oid
from dbo.patient as p
where p.rpid = ledger.rpid
order by p.oid) AS p
group by RPID
order by rpid
```

I pieced this together from two different queries, that work individually but when combined returns no results.

I want to group `PATID` and `SUM(AMOUNT)` from the `ledger` table, but add the `OID` from the `patient` table to the result that matches on the `RPID` column. I am fine taking ANY matching `OID` (between `RPID` in `ledger` and `RPID` in `patient` tables) as `RPID` only exists once in the `patient` table - this is why I used the MIN function but it could be anything.

EXAMPLE:

```
LEDGER TABLE

RPID    AMOUNT
100      25
100      30
100      30
110      50
110      50

PATIENT TABLE

RPID    OID
100     10
110     20

RESULT

RPID    AMOUNT    OID
100     85        10
110     100       20
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the desired output?

Comment: Why did you use apply here? wasnt join sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

If the result you want is:

```
RPID    AMOUNT    OID
100     85        10
110     100       20
```

then a simple join between the tables and a sum of amount would get you that:

```
select 
    l.rpid, 
    sum(l.amount) as amount, 
    p.oid as HomeID 
from ledger as l
join dbo.patient as p on p.rpid = l.rpid
group by l.RPID, p.OID
```

There's no need to use apply at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `CROSS APPLY` to `JOIN`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5273c/4

```
select l.rpid, sum(l.amount) as amount, min(p.oid) as HomeID 
from ledger l
join patient p on l.rpid = p.rpid
group by l.rpid
order by l.rpid
```

But version with `CROSS APPLY` also works:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5273c/1

Comment: What's the point of `min` if _RPID only exists once in the patient table_ as the question states?

Comment: @jpw, it doesnt metter. You can group by both or group by one and apply aggregation.

Comment: But it does matter. If the `rpid` is indeed unique in the `patient` table then including `min` makes the query almost twice as expensive. If it's not a 1:1 mapping in `patient` using `min` would be appropriate (and change the meaning of the query which seem to be what the OP wants - maybe the assertion that `rpid` is unique isn't correct).

Comment: @jpw, yes execution plan with aggregation is worse. But I dont know why OP used apply.  If there are just unique patients then of course grouping by both column is better